# Which framework as used to make this contact page (dynamic / moving)

Tags: jquery, html, css, node.js, angularjs

I came across [this web site](https://www.quebecinternational.ca/en/contact-us), and I'd like to know which framework did they use to make "Contact" page Form element such as textbox (Name, Enterprise...) when you click on it, its moving (reducing its size)...

also when you hover social media icons, it's increase its size.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        // Show an alert popup message.
        alert('Hello World From JQuery.');

        // Get the button object by it's id.
        var button = jQuery('#click_button')

        // When click this button then execute below function.
        button.bind('click', function () {

            // Get button original text.
            const original_text = jQuery(this).text();


            jQuery(this).text('Wish you like JQuery :)').css({color:'yellow', background:'blue'});
        })
```

Open link below

[www.quebecinternational.ca/en/contact-us](https://www.quebecinternational.ca/en/contact-us)

Comment: Seems they are using ember. The animations you see on hover for example are pure css.

Comment: Javascript framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework used is [Ember 3.5](https://emberjs.com/) combined with jQuery.

A quick tip: if you use Chrome and want to see which frameworks etc. are used, check out the following link:

[Wappalyzer](https://www.wappalyzer.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool. It is will show you what all is used to built these site. It also comes with chrome extension
https://builtwith.com/